# Switch em configuração Application.ini ZF 1

Tags: php, zend, switch

Dentro do Application.ini do Zend Framework 1 tenho o seguinte configuração:

```
resources.multidb.sga.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.sga.host = "host.acula.net"
resources.multidb.sga.username  = "usuario"
resources.multidb.sga.password  = "senha"
resources.multidb.sga.port  = "3306"
resources.multidb.sga.dbname  = "base"
```

Porém eu preciso que o **HOST seja dinâmico**. Ele será alterado conforme a escolha em uma Switch no Controller.

```
switch ($unidade) {
            case 'Gama':

                $host = 'sgagama.servidor.br';
                $unidade = 5;

                $this->realizaConsultaSga($mes, $ano, $unidade);

                break;

        case 'Sede':

                $host = 'sgasede.servidor.br';
                $unidade = 1;

                $this->realizaConsultaSga($mes, $ano, $unidade);

        break;
....
```

Como faço para que isso funcione nessa ideia?

Comment: Problema foi resolvido com base nesse link do próprio zend.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Você pode modificar as configurações de database no bootstrap.
[Nesse link](http://www.blogalizado.com.br/conectar-em-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-com-zend-framework/) tem um exemplo de como usar múltiplos databases.
Basta você informar qual database quer utilizar.

> Adicione as conexões no seu arquivo
>   “application/configs/application.ini”:
>
> ```
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.params.host = "127.0.0.1"
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.params.username = "root"
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.params.password = "root"
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.params.dbname = "nome_banco_1"
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.charset = "UTF-8"
> resources.db.nome_banco_1.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
> resources.db.nome_banco_2.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
> resources.db.nome_banco_2.params.host = "127.0.0.1"
> resources.db.nome_banco_2.params.username = "root"
> resources.db.nome_banco_2.params.password = "root"
> resources.db.nome_banco_2.params.dbname = "nome_banco_2"
> resources.db.nome_banco_2.charset = "UTF-8"
> ```
>
> Altere o arquivo “application/Bootstrap.php”:
>
> ```
> class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
> {
>     protected function _initDb()
>     {
>         $config = new Zend_Config_Ini('application/configs/application.ini');
>         $dbAdapters = array();
>         foreach($config->{APPLICATION_ENV}->resources->db as $config_name => $db){
>             $dbAdapters[$config_name] = Zend_Db::factory($db->adapter,$db->params->toArray());
>             if((boolean)$db->isDefaultTableAdapter){
>                 Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapters[$config_name]);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> E agora basta informar em cada model qual é a conexão correspondente:
>
> ```
> class Application_Model_DbTable_NomeTabela extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
> {
>     protected $_schema = "nome_banco_1";
>     protected $_name = "nome_tabela";
> }
> ```

Comment: Mas a única coisa que muda é o host, os outros dados são iguais.